# Which one class classifiers are available in WEKA?

Tags: algorithm, classification, weka, biometrics

I should use one class classifiers on my dataset. I have 17 users and already tested those with the one-class SVM from the libSVM. But I have the advice to test other one class classifiers too. When I'm searching in weka for unary class, highlighted in blue, I cannot use them because they cannot handle an unary class because they don't use a one class classifier. I tried to google for a list of one class classifiers but didn't find anything except the SVM.

For Example: if I search for unary class he suggested me to use LWL but when I'm using LWL he uses DecisionStump which is an binary class classifier.

Dataset is like:

Username - Size_average - Size_min - Size_max
User1 - 0,31111112 - 0,26666668 - 0,33333334
User1 - 0,315555564 - 0,26666668 - 0,33333334
User1 - 0,26666668 - 0,26666668 - 0,26666668
...

I want to identifiy the user with an accuracy value. The user should be a class attribute with only a single label. Which classifiers are one class classifiers that I can use? Or is there a way to make an mulitclass classifier to an one class classifier?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the oneClassClassifier1.0.4. http://sourceforge.net/projects/weka/files/weka-packages/

My other problem was that I cannot install the package so I used the newer Version of Weka
http://www.cs.waikato.ac.nz/ml/weka/downloading.html

Answer (score 0):

I've had really similar *testing* problem, where I've had to use unary classification. Weka's *OneClassClassifier* (exactly what You have linked) solved me the problem.

For You other problem: Im working on a Mac and using weka in a Matlab project. The older version of weka did not work for me, so I had to make one common jar from *v3.7+ weka.jar* and *OneClassClassifier.jar*. With this I managed to use weka's one class classifier.